# A Click Counter - MySQL -

Tags: java, php, mysql, counter

I work for a TV producer and we have a very simple (and VERY stupid) idea. I can't divulge the actual idea, but this is the gist of my objective:

-A line of text reads: "Click the button if you like bread"

-User clicks "I like bread" button, button goes away and counter increases by +1

I know I need to use a database to ensure that the count remains true each time the page is opened from anywhere, but I'm not sure how to get the counter and the button on the same page?

I made one that worked-- with an index.html document that housed the button, but it directed to a separate PHP document that had the counter.

Ideally, unique visitors could only click the button once. But that's not 100% necessary if it's a pain in the ass for anyone to answer.

I really appreciate any help with this.

Thank you!

Comment: So... Have you made anything?

Comment: Leave a cookie saying that they have clicked the button. If the cookie is set don't count it. This will fail to work if a user is very determined, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To make it stay one one page use **AJAX**. Here is a simple example:(using jQuery)

HTML:

```
<div id='Click'>CLICK HERE<div/>
```

JS:

```
$('#Click').click(function(){
    $().ajax({
    url: "www.yourdomain.com/location/of/script.php",
    type: 'POST',
    //Not sure if this is necessary.
    data:{Click: '1'},
    success: function(result){
        $('#Click').text('the Count is: '+result);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
     Whatever your php script does
?>
```